# How to set macOS coding language from terminal - Flutter

Tags: objective-c, macos, flutter

I added a macOS platform to an existing Flutter project, and I'm using Objective C as a main coding language for iOS.

I used the following command when I created the platform:

```
flutter create --org package_name .
```

If you want to set the coding language for iOS you will use:

```
flutter create --org package_name . -i objc
```

But there is nothing mentioned about how I can set the coding language for macOS
The macOS project has been created using Swift language by default

Any ideas?

Comment: i am facing the same problem. have you find any solution? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution, so I created the project using Swift language and I used the headers bridge to write objective c code @ch271828n